# How to make photo album private in Facebook using C# SDK

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk, privacy

I am developing a winform (desktop) application in C#. How can I create an Album using the Facebook API and also set its privacy as "ONLY ME"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is described for `albums` connection of `user`. You need to use `privacy` field.

```
http://graph.facebook.com/me/albums?name=Demo&privacy={"value":"SELF"}&method=post
```

Beware:

> **Privacy Policy:** Any non-default privacy setting must be intentionally chosen by the user. You may not set a custom privacy setting unless the user has proactively specified that they want this non-default setting.

For more details on albums `privacy` settings read documentation for [`albums` connection](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#albums).